# how to automate mouse clicks in nw.js (node-webkit)

Tags: node.js, selenium, chromium, node-webkit, nw.js

I have a nw.js app using mean stack i have an canvas inside my app I want to emulate actions on (click/drag/type). my go to tool is selenium but it requires to open a new window.
how would I go automating this? I dont want to do all my actions inside the nw.js window (chromium)
or is it possbile to start nw.js using selenium?

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more. Is there a new window popup when you are dealing with our application?

Comment: Hi @shah i have an external website i want to test using selenium framework. I want the site to be embedded inside my nw.js application. Idiealy in an iframe.  Or some kind of embedded browser.  Unfortunately i cannot attach selenium to an activr browser instnace.

Comment: Eg i want to avoid creating a new window

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to test your website but you don't want a window being popped up while testing. You can handle this situation by installing PhantomJS and then changing the:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

to

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

This way you can hide the browser popup. However, for debugging purposes , then you need to put `driver.save_screenshot('abc.png')` wherever you need to see what is happening.

Comment: No.  I want to actually see whay is going on.